# Java 2D array cannot write values into the last values index

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception, 2d

I have an issue with my Java 2D array.

```
int y = 5;
int x = 4;
int[][] map = new int[y][x];

for (int j = 0; j <= y ; j++) {
    for (int l = 0; l <=x; l++) {
        System.out.println("j: " + j + " l: " + l);
        map[j][l] = 1;
    }
}
```

Java throws this exception when it reaches the last values in the array:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
```

Changing the for loop to "j < y" and "l < x" helps solving the problem, but column 5 and row 4 doesn't obviously get printed.

[image: Picture showing the changed code ( < instead of <=]

Is there any way to fix this, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because arrays in Java are `0`-indexed, the length of the array is **not** a valid index. For that reason, you should use `<` instead of `<=` in your for-loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
    for (int l = 0; l < x; l++) {
        System.out.println("j: " + j + " l: " + l);
        map[j][l] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, thank you, I thought that array length is indexed from 0 as well - but it apparently isn't right?

Comment: @Radek The last addressable index of `array` is `array.length - 1` (because it's indexed from `0`)

Answer (score 0):

Java `arrays` are `0` indexed so remove `=` in `for` loop.

```
int y = 5;
int x = 4;
int[][] map = new int[y][x];

for (int j = 0; j < y ; j++) {
    for (int l = 0; l <x; l++) {
        System.out.println("j: " + j + " l: " + l);
        map[j][l] = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove equals from both loops

```
    int y = 5;
    int x = 4;
    int[][] map = new int[y][x];

    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < x; l++) {
            System.out.println("j: " + j + " l: " + l);
            map[j][l] = 1;
        }
    }
```

There is no column as 5 since the size of that is 5. So indexes go like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. Same goes for the row 4 one. Since size is 4 on that one, the indexes will go like 0, 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 0):

In java, array index are from `0` to `length-1`.

So, in your case, from `0` to `y-1 = 4` and from `0` to `x-1 = 3`. Your output seems perfectly okay. The first value of `j` should be 0. You have 5 different values for `j`, and 4 different values for `l`.

Change back `<=` to `<` in the for loop. (This part causes the error : `l` cannot go from `0` to `4`, only from `0` to `3`)